# The siunitx package messes with manually input thousand-separators

Tags: siunitx

Recently I found the very useful `siunitx` package, and immediately looked to use it for some tables. Unfortunately, I already have all my numbers typeset with `,` thousand separator and `.` decimal separator.

If I try something like:

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=6.2]}
 300,000.12\\
 \end{tabular}
 \end{document}
```

I get errors like:

```
Duplicate decimal marker '.' in input.
```

If I replace `300,000.12` with `300,000` it considers it as the `300.000` (i.e., `300`).

This seems strange to me as the package interprets `300000` as `300,000` but it interprets `300,000` as `300.000`.

I've scanned through the detailed `siunitx` documentation, but could not find any flags for picking up input separators. Anyone know how `siunitx` can be parameterised to treat raw input numbers like 300,000.12 gracefully?

(I would rather not remove all commas from all input numbers.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can tell `siunitx` to ignore certain characters by using `input-ignore={<list of characters>}`. However, since the comma is by default one of the decimal separators `siunitx` looks for, just adding `,` to the `input-ignore` list won't work: You also have to tell `siunitx` that only periods are decimal markers, using `input-decimal-markers={.}` (by default it is set to `{,.}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.}}
\begin{document}
\num{300,000.12}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding back in `group-separator={,}` keeps the comma in the output. Thanks! (I think this should be default behaviour for the package: to consider comma as a thousands separator in the input to keep consistent with the output.)

Comment: @badroit You are mistaking setting the _output_ group separator for 'keeping' the material you have in the _input_. The `siunitx` package parses your input, then typesets it according to the current settings. The standard settings use a thin space as a group separator as this is recommended by a number of authorities.

Comment: @Joseph, understood. This is also be a good opportunity to say thanks for a great package!