# Preserving thousands separator with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm writing a paper and my advisor is requiring that all large numbers have a comma as a thousands separator. I've read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51572/the-siunitx-package-messes-with-manually-input-thousand-separators?rq=1) which asks about how to make `siunitx` not throw errors when there is a comma in the input, but how can I force a comma in the output when using `\SI`?

Ideally it would only do it for numbers with more than 4 digits -- ie. `\SI{9000}` would not contain a space or comma but `\SI{10000}` would be `10,000`. But if that's not possible, I'd settle for `9,000` also.

Comment: Your advisor is wrong. The only acceptable separator for thousands is a thin space, both for the ISO and good typography.

Comment: @egreg I would agree completely if he didn't sign the paychecks and hold this paper not being done over my head as a reason for delaying my thesis proposal. Graduating >> commas.

Comment: I sympathize with you. After all, getting the right typesetting is just commenting one line in the source file. `;-)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is described in section **5.6 Printing numbers** of the manual (for v. 2.5s, dated 2013/07/31). The `group-separator` key defines the separator between groups of digits. By default grouping is not applied for numbers with four digits (e.g. 9000), so there's no need to do anything for that.  (This can be changed with `group-minimum-digits`, which defines how many digits must be present for grouping to apply.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}
\begin{document}
\SI{9000}{\m}

\SI{90000}{\m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So I had tried what I assumed was equivalent with `\sisetup{group-separator = {\,},` but apparently `\,` does not behave the same as just `,`

Comment: @tpg2114 No, `\,` is a thin space.

Comment: Lots of time wasted... sigh. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: The key `group-minimum-digits=5` is not necessary here because it is set by default. The grouping of four digits can explicitly be set by `group-four-digits`.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig Oops, you're right, seems I should read the manual more thoroughly ... Thanks!

Comment: "group-minimum digits" should be changed to "group-minimum-digits" in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The thin space for group separator can be achieved by using `\text{}`, thus circumventing the build-in removal of spaces in the `\num{}` handler.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = \text{\,}}
\begin{document}
\SI{9000}{\m}

\SI{90000}{\m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  In the comments, the poster specifically says that this is not what is wanted.  In any case, the thin space is what `siunitx` provides by default here, see page 27 of the manual.

Comment: Spaces are stripped out of input on parsing: what happens when formatting is a separate step.