# ACM TAPS compatible siunitx replacement for thousands separator

Tags: siunitx, acmart

I would like to format large numbers like 31556952000 with a thousands separator as 31,556,952,000. Adding `\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}` in the preamble and `\num{31556952000}` in the body has worked quite well, but is not suitable for ACM TAPS submission as `siunitx` is not on [the approved list of packages](https://authors.acm.org/proceedings/production-information/accepted-latex-packages). As [Preserving thousands separator with siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133993/28176), this is an imposed requirement.

How may I get comma-separated thousands using only packages supported by ACM TAPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the core loop from `siunitx` and writing out, we'd get something like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\providecommand*\num[2][]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \num@auxi{0}{}#2\num@q@stop
  }%
}
\newcommand\num@auxi{}
\long\def\num@auxi#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#3\num@q@stop
    \expandafter\num@auxiii
  \else
    \expandafter\num@auxii
  \fi
    {#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand\num@auxiii[3]{%
  \expandafter\num@auxiv\expandafter
    {\number\numexpr#1\relax}{#2}%
}
\newcommand\num@auxii[3]{\num@auxi{#1 + 1}{#2#3}}
\newcommand\num@auxiv[2]{%
  \@nameuse{num@aux@\number\numexpr#1-(\@num@div#1;3;)*3\relax}{#2}%
}
\long\@namedef{num@aux@0}#1{%
  \num@loop@first#1\num@q@stop
}
\long\@namedef{num@aux@1}#1{%
  \num@loop@first{}{}#1\num@q@stop
}
\long\@namedef{num@aux@2}#1{%
  \num@loop@first{}#1\num@q@stop
}
\newcommand\num@loop@first[4]{%
  #1#2#3%
  \ifx#4\num@q@stop
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\num@loop
  \fi
    #4%
}
\newcommand\num@loop[4]{%
  \mathord{,}%
  #1#2#3%
  \ifx#4\num@q@stop
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\num@loop
  \fi
    #4%
}
\newcommand\@num@div{}
\long\def\@num@div#1#2;#3#4;{%
 \ifx0#1%
   0%
 \else
   (#1#2\ifx-#1+\else-\fi(\ifx-#3-\fi#3#4-1)/2)%
 \fi /#3#4%
}
\def\nume@q@stop{\nume@q@stop}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\num{31556952000}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Dumped that in `lib/num.tex` then added `\input{lib/num}` to the preamble.